How to convert from a BOOST_TEST (relative tolerance) to an equivalent GTest EXPECT_NEAR (absolute tolerance)?
I am tasked with changing some Boost tests over to GTest. I have a bunch of tests of the form:
const double toleranceValue = 1.0e-10;
const auto tolerance = boost::test_tolerance::tolerance(toleranceValue);
BOOST_TEST(value, expectedValue, tolerance);

What's the equivalent GTest for this? I tried:
// Extra 100 factor to convert from BOOST_TEST's assuming the tolerance is a percentage
EXPECT_NEAR(value, expectedValue, expectedValue * toleranceValue);

but when expectedValue is zero, the overall tolerance value is zero and it fails when value isn't exactly zero.
What is the right way to adapt this BOOST_TEST to EXPECT_NEAR?

Given the definition of relative tolerance in Boost:

Assertions in the Unit Test Framework use two kinds of comparison. For u being close to zero with absolute tolerance eps:
abs(u) <= eps; // (abs)

For u and v being close with relative tolerance eps:
   abs(u - v)/abs(u) <= eps
&& abs(u - v)/abs(v) <= eps; // (rel)

[...] Assertion BOOST_TEST (when comparing floating-point numbers) uses the following algorithm:

When either value u or v is zero, evaluates formula (abs) on the other value.
When the specified tolerance is zero, performs direct (native) comparison between u and v.
Otherwise, performs formula (rel) on u and v.


There is nothing corresponding to that in GoogleTest. You will have to write your own predicate, e.g.,
bool IsNearRelative(double u, double v, double eps){
    if(u == 0) {
        return abs(v) < eps;
    } 
    if (v == 0) {
        return abs(u) < eps;
    }
    if (eps == 0) {
        return u == v;
    }
    return abs(u - v)/abs(u) <= eps && abs(u - v)/abs(v) <= eps; 
}
EXPECT_TRUE(IsNearRelative(value, expectedValue, tolerance));


Note that GoogleTest provides different approaches to testing floating point values for near equality: EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ will check if values are within 4 ULPs of each other and EXPECT_NEAR will check if values are within absolute difference.

You likely meant
const auto tolerance = tt::tolerance(1.0e-10);
BOOST_TEST(value, expectedValue, tolerance);

You can make it like
const auto tolerance = 1.0e-10;
EXPECT_NEAR(value - expectedValue, 0, (expectedValue ? expectedValue : value) * tolerance);


I did mean that, thanks. I updated my question to include the tt::tolerance.
